# Class constants with type of class

Tags: python-3.x

I do have a class with multiple methods in which I'd like to add constant values of instances of this class, to keep common used combinations handy.

```py
class Text:
    GREETING = Text('Hello')
    LOREM = Text('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amen')

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def double(self):
        return f'{self.text}, {self.text}'
```

This doesn't work in that way (*Undefined name 'Text'*). I could declare the constants later on:

```py
Text.GREETING = Text('Hello')
Text.LOREM = Text('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amen')
```

But that doesn't seem quite nice to me. I'd like to have it all inside of the class definition to be able to document everything nicely. Is there any other way possible?

Comment: Why not use `enum` ?

Comment: The problem is that inside the class definition the class is still not defined (you are defining it now) so you can't use it to create instances. What would you think about a class method that registers these common globals?

Comment: "But that doesn't seem quite nice to me" well, that's your only option, really. You *could* create some `@classmethod` that adds those constants to the class, but you still have to call it manually after

Comment: @bigbounty: The real objects are quite more complex. Using enums doesn't make any sense in this case to me. Say the class would be car and I would like to add some commonly used cars. VW Golf, Skoda Octavia, … I could use a enum if I only have one parameter (e.g. size). But not if I have multiple independent attributes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That would be possible indeed, but I'd have to call it anyway. At least I would capsulate the actual creation.

Comment: Please clarify what your actual use-case is. This can be done either via metaclasses or decorators (which basically do the ``Text.GREETING = Text('Hello')`` for you) but has *lots* of possibilities (e.g. lazy, dynamic, ...). Note that an enum can have multiple values in the form of containers – e.g. a tuple.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I edited my question. I do have multiple methods in that class that calculate something out of the attributes. Maybe I'm getting enums wrong but for me they are only some type of flag or container for data, not manipulating them.

Comment: Enums are allowed to have methods, so what you are showing is no problem. Do you intend to create more, possibly short-lived instances outside of the class body as well?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes! I do! I'd only like to provide some preconfigured instances for convenience for often used configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this look better to you?

```py
class Text:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, name, text):
        setattr(cls, name, text)

Text.register('GREETING', 'hello')
Text.register('LOREM', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amen')
```

EDIT:
In case you need this pattern for multiple classes, it can be easily extracted to a separate class and use it as a Mixin:

```py
class Registry:
    @classmethod
    def register(cls, name, text):
        setattr(cls, name, text)

class Text(Registry):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

Text.register('GREETING', 'hello')
Text.register('LOREM', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amen')
```

Comment: Indeed it does. It doesn't solve the problem directly but 'streamlines' the generation of those base classes.

Comment: If you want to have multiple classes with this pattern you can always move the classmethod to a parent class from where the other classes inherit. I will edit my answer to add this.

Answer (score 2):

You might make use of class- or static methods, if you don't mind the extra paranthesis and construction at call site:

```py
class Text:
    @staticmethod
    def lorem():
        return Text("Lorem ipsum")
    # or
    @classmethod
    def greeting(cls):
        return cls("Hello")
```

Comment: That would be great, especially if I'd use the 'constants' as bases that could be modified afterwards – if I recall the Method, the Text would be regenerated.